# How to use multiple API's in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, cors, fiddler

I want to call multiple API's in Vue.js something like this:

```
<script>
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            array1: [],
            array2: []
        },
        created(){
            fetch('http://localhost/api/first')
            .then(Response => Response.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.array1 = json
            }),

            fetch('http://localhost/api/second')
            .then(Response => Response.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.array2 = json
            })
        }
    })
</script>
```

When I use the Vue devtools in Chrome I can see that the 2 arrays are recognised and when I use Fiddler I can see that both the APIs are called. The problem is the second set of JSON results i.e. from `http://localhost/api/second` don't populate `array2`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean `this.array1` has value and `this.array2` is empty array after API is called? Can you confirm `http://localhost/api/second` return a non-empty array?

Comment: Yes this.array1 has values and this.array2 is empty; http://localhost/api/second returns some data ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question in case anyone else hits a similar problem. Firstly the code in the question above works fine. My problem was that CORS was not enabled on the server side for the http://localhost/api/second API and it needed to be. Fiddler was not effected by the CORS restriction and hence fetched the API results just fine.